# Where can I buy an xbox live subscription with BTC?

Tags: transactions

I'm looking for the best place to buy an xbox live 3 month subscription for the european region...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft accepts Bitcoin to fund your account. From the following link: https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub/Help/Right?helppagename=CSV_BitcoinHowTo.htm

> To add money to your Microsoft account with Bitcoin:
>
> 1. Sign in to Microsoft account - Billing with your Microsoft account
> 2. Select Payment options > Microsoft account > redeem bitcoin
> 3. Select the amount you want to add, then click Next
> 4. Review the amount of Bitcoin needed and use your digital wallet to complete the transaction within 15 minutes:
>
>    - On your computer – select Pay with Bitcoin and then pay from your        Bitcoin wallet on the same device.
>    - On your smartphone – scan the QR      code displayed on the page to    pay from your mobile wallet app.
>    - If your wallet is on another device, you can copy the receiving address     and BTC amount to the wallet on your device or the Web and
>        then make     your purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried them myself so do some research to find genuine feedback or reviews, seems some activity on reddit for that. But this website seems to offer what you are after.

https://xbl4btc.com/

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=950320.0